# Force DnX Mode on ASUS Android Tablet/Intel Cloverview

Tags: android, bootloader

I have an Asus MeMo Pad 7 (ME70CX KO1A, Intel Cloverview Chipset) which is not bootable. The device sticks at the bootloader splash screen and no button combination will force the device into droidboot, DnX, or recovery. If I can get the device into DnX mode (Intel's Download aNd eXecute mode), I can reflash the bootloader and recover the device. The problem is, it will only enter this mode if the bootloader is missing.

Is there a way to force DnX mode, perhaps by communicating with the hardware at a low level (i.e. UART)?

Answer (score 1):

First, install and run xFSTK. Then while device is powered off, press and hold `Vol-` (maybe `Vol+` or both, try all) while connected to PC via MicroUSB. The xFSTK will recognize device's chip immediately and allows you to flash four files to the device:

- dnx_os
- dnx_fw
- ifwi_os
- droidboot.bin

That's enough for us to unbrick our devices. My phone is ZenFone 5, and when I developed on it, it hard bricked many times like yours.